# How to rebroadcast a WiFi signal?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

There is a community WiFi network in my village that is free to use to anyone who sends in their MAC address. I have talked with the network administrator, and he says it would be fine to rebroadcast it as my own network, as it only has signal at the top of my house. How would I rebroadcast the signal through a router at minimal budget?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They sell [wireless repeaters](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006J1ZAR2) for just the task.  What could be free to do, if you already have a wireless router that [supports simultaneous dual band](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833122326&nm_mc=KNC-GoogleAdwords&cm_mmc=KNC-GoogleAdwords-_-pla-_-Wireless%20Routers-_-N82E16833122326&gclid=CMmXpdHf77UCFYqf4AodNUQAxQ) (802.11N & 802.11G), is connect to the village network with one band (802.11N for instance) then set up a  separate private network for you on the other band (802.11G).

Comment: would [this](http://www.amazon.co.uk/TP-Link-TL-WA830RE-300Mbps-Wireless-Extender/dp/B006BBYXPA/ref=sr_1_10?ie=UTF8&qid=1362859538&sr=8-10) one work to make my own personal network with the connection  from the WiFi?

Comment: Looks like it should do the trick.